# Select part of the elements of a Series using isin

Tags: pandas, series, mutable

I have a dataset with several columns. One of them is day where I store the day of the row. I also have a list of days that I want to study (called days) and I want to only keep the rows corresponding those the days that belong to this list.

Therefore, I have written:

```
dat = data[data.day.isin(days)]
```

And then, I have the Following error message:

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: How do you declare days

Comment: There actually nothing wrong with your code, so there is an issue with your DataFrame data, or your list days.